# Using tf.name_scope in Tensorboard with Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have some code to calculate performance metrics within my `Estimator` model_fn written in a function that returns a dictionary of metrics

```
def __model_eval_metrics(self, classes, labels, mode):
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN or mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return {
                'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1), predictions=classes),
                'precision': tf.metrics.precision(labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1), predictions=classes),
                'recall': tf.metrics.recall(labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1), predictions=classes)
                }
    else:
        return None
```

During estimator **training**, these are logged as scalers within `model_fn` grouped by the name scope "train_metrics"

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    with tf.name_scope('train_metrics') as scope:
        tf.summary.scalar('model_accuracy', eval_metrics['accuracy'][1])
        tf.summary.scalar('model_precision', eval_metrics['precision'][1])
        tf.summary.scalar('model_recall', eval_metrics['recall'][1])
        tf.summary.scalar('model_loss', loss)
```

This produces the desired grouping in Tensorboard
[image: Tensorboard Example]

For `Estimator` **evaluation**, the metrics are passed as a dictionary to `EstimatorSpec` eval_metric_ops argument as the result of `__model_eval_metrics()`

```
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode,
    predictions={"predictions": predictions, "classes": classes},
    loss=loss,
    train_op=train_op,
    eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics,
)
```

The problem is that in Tensorboard, these metrics are no longer grouped by name scope and I cannot figure out where to add a name scope to make this happen. You can see that evaluation metrics are ungrouped.

[image: Tensorboard wrong]

**Question**

1. Is there an approach to leveraging name_scope for evaluation metrics with `Estimator`?
2. Should I just be ignoring name_scope altogether and just toggle the runs on the bottom-left of the Tensorboard screen?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the same "folder" prefix for the metric name (eval) as the name scope for summary (train):

```
r2 = metrics_r2(labels, predictions)
metrics = {'metrics/r2': r2}
with tf.name_scope('metrics'):
    tf.summary.scalar('r2', r2[1])

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=m_loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)
```

[image]